# checkable spinner for android app

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

I am working on a mapView app and I would like to have a button much like the layer button in google maps that allows someone to show or hide an option from a spinner.  I have searched to try and find how to accomplish this but have been unsuccessful.  Can someone point me in the right direction of what to search for or what to implement?

Answer (score 0):

you can just make a custom view that has bunch of checkboxes and textviews (stacked horizontally as a bunch of relativelayouts stacked in a linearlayout). this is probably easy enough to do if you don't have a ton of items. (I'm assuming you don't because you referred to the maps options)